# Bernoulli's principle in a closed loop?

Tags: fluid-dynamics

In most simple terms, Bernoulli's principle dictates that

- a fluid or gas moving in one direction exposes less pressure in orthogonal directions.
- the sum of the pressures, in the direction of movement and otherwise, is equal the pressure as measured in rest.

Essentially, we loose static pressure and gain dynamic pressure. At least, that's the version we are taught in aerodynamics.

Imagine a bicycle tire being filled with air. Imagine it being freely suspended, and within a vacuum. Imagine spinning it up from rest. During acceleration, the tire is constantly somewhat faster than the air within. Considering both reference frames equal, the air moves through the tire, so the tire should lose some diameter.

So my question is: If the "total pressure" remains unchanged, where is the missing pressure applied? Or if that's paradoxical, what’s wrong with my initial description of Bernoulli's principle?